# C# Приближение полиномами Чебышева

Tags: c#, интерполяция

Нужно програмно реализовать приближения (интерполяцию) функции полинонами Чебышева. Т.е. у нас есть n-ое количество пар x,y, и нужно по заданному x получить приблизительный y.

Приближающая функция ищется в виде суммы многочленов Чебыше­ва, т. е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал реализовать, пока безуспешно

```
  public class Polynom
    {
        public double[] X { get; set; }
        public double[] Y { get; set; }

        public Polynom(double[] x, double[] y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public Polynom(List<DoublePoint> list)
        {
            X = new double[list.Count];
            Y = new double[list.Count];
            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                X[j] = i.X;
                Y[j] = i.Y;
                j++;
            }
        }

        public double GetY(double x)
        {
            double res = GetRatio(0, X.Length) * (1 / Math.Pow(2, 0.5)); //отдельно считаем первое слогаемое (для Т с тильдой)
            for (int i = 1; i < X.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                res += (GetRatio(i, X.Length) * GetChebPolynom(x, i)); //сумма многочленов
            }
            return res; 
        }

        public double GetChebPolynom(double x, long n) //считаем многочлен
        {
            if (n == 1) return x;
            double result = Math.Cos(n * Math.Acos(x));
            return result;
        }

        public double GetRatio(double j, double n)
        {
            double res = Y[0] * 1; //отдельно считаем первое слогаемое (для Т без тильды)
        for (var i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                res +=  Y[i] * GetChebPolynom(X[i], (long)j);
            }
            return res * 2 / n;
        }

    }
```

Класc DoublePoint:

```
public class DoublePoint : IComparable
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public DoublePoint(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста, укажите мне на мои ошибки. Буду рад любой помощи.

Возможно, я не до конца понял этот метод. Ведь я так и не понял, для чего формула, которая вычисляет Xj. И не знаю, правильно ли я считаю полиномы.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: f(x) -это функция, а у Вас в коде я не заметил её

Comment: @nuts119
Да, я уже разобрался. Оказывается, такое приближение возможно лишь когда функция задана аналитически. раньше я предполагал, что можно использовать те значения, которые мы получили в табличном виде.